# Detect UIImagePicker live view touches without "grabbing" them

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing an app that allows the user to take pictures, using an UIImagePickerController.

I have customized the UIImagePicker with my own button bar and a few other button/options (views) added over the imagePicker view. Heres the relevant code:

```
self.photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.photoPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.photoPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;

[self.photoPicker.view addSubview:topButtonView];
[self.photoPicker.view addSubview:topButtonView2];
```

Everything is working as expected except for one problem. I began by targeting this app for iOS 4 and above, and one of the features I needed to have is the tap-to-focus functionality that comes embedded in the UIImagePickerController. Here is the problem. On iOS 4, when the user taps the live view, gets (presented automatically by the picker controller) a visual indicator (a square shape) showing the point were the camera is focusing and adjusting exposure. On iOS 5 and 6 that visual indicator is gone. The functionality  (tap-to-foucus) is still there, but no more square showing the user the place where the focus point is set.

I have searched and read several similar questions (but not quite), and the answers usually point to adding a transparent subview over the  UIImagePicker live view and capture the touch event. And that is easy enough, but the problem is, after I capture the users touch, I have found no way of relaying that touch to the UIImagePicker liveView.

I tried to create a custom view class to add over de imagepicker view but haven't been able to make it work. Here is the custom class code:

```
@interface touchGrabberViewController : UIViewController 
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
CGPoint tapPoint;
__unsafe_unretained IBOutlet UIImageView *tapFocusIndicator;
NSTimer *indicatorDismisser;

}

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *photoPicker;

@end



@implementation touchGrabberViewController

@synthesize photoPicker;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tapFocusIndicator.hidden = YES;
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return photoPicker.view;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;

   tapPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [self showTapFocusIndicator];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


- (void)showTapFocusIndicator
{

    if (!indicatorDismisser)
    {
        tapFocusIndicator.center = tapPoint;

        tapFocusIndicator.hidden = NO;

        indicatorDismisser = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(hideTapFocusIndicatorWithTimer:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:NO];
    }

}

- (void)hideTapFocusIndicatorWithTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    tapFocusIndicator.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(resetTapFocusIndicator)];
    tapFocusIndicator.alpha = 0.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [indicatorDismisser invalidate];
    indicatorDismisser = nil;
}

- (void)resetTapFocusIndicator
{
    tapFocusIndicator.hidden = YES;
    tapFocusIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

With this class I get a very similar visual indicator showing up were the user taps, but the user touches never get relayed back to the live view, so the focus functionality is lost.

Recently I decided to drop iOS 4, and just target versions 5 and 6, but I miss that visual indicator. As a camera apps user the indicator is really useful.

I have beeen experimenting alternatives with (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event, but no luck.

Anyone has any idea on how to achieve this, or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.